# DevExtreme: Return Object from Spring Rest Api does not bind with dxDataGrid

Tags: datagrid, devexpress, devextreme

Could any one help me how could I bind data object with DevExtreme's dxDataGrid using customstore.

My DTO is like:

[

data: {...},
  totalCount: 100,
  summary: [10,20,30]

]

But when i bind the data with dxDataGrid it just bind data but not totalCount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for my problem.

```
[remoteOperations]="true"
```

I need remoteOperations = true to bind the totalCount along with data fetched from the server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to send a *totalCount*, you have to use the **summary section** istead, look at [this sample](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/GridSummaries/jQuery/Light/)

```
$("#gridContainer").dxDataGrid({
        dataSource: orders,
        keyExpr: "ID",
        showBorders: true,
        selection: {
            mode: "single"
        },
        columns: [{
                dataField: "OrderNumber",
                width: 130,
                caption: "Invoice Number"
            }, {
                dataField: "OrderDate",
                dataType: "date",
                width: 160
            }, 
            "Employee", {
                caption: "City",
                dataField: "CustomerStoreCity"
            }, {
                caption: "State",
                dataField: "CustomerStoreState"  
            }, {
                dataField: "SaleAmount",
                alignment: "right",
                format: "currency"
            }
        ],
        summary: {
            totalItems: [{
                column: "OrderNumber",
                summaryType: "count"
            }]
        }
    });
```

---

Data Source

```
var orders = [{
    "ID" : 1,
    "OrderNumber" : 35703,
    "OrderDate" : "2014-04-10",
    "SaleAmount" : 11800,
    "Terms" : "15 Days",
    "TotalAmount" : 12175,
    "CustomerStoreState" : "California",
    "CustomerStoreCity" : "Los Angeles",
    "Employee" : "Harv Mudd"
}, {
    "ID" : 4,
    "OrderNumber" : 35711,
    "OrderDate" : "2014-01-12",
    "SaleAmount" : 16050,
    "Terms" : "15 Days",
    "TotalAmount" : 16550,
    "CustomerStoreState" : "California",
    "CustomerStoreCity" : "San Jose",
    "Employee" : "Jim Packard"
}....
]
```

---

For [custom summaries you can use this](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/DataGrid/CustomSummaries/jQuery/Light/)

```
summary: {
            totalItems: [{
                    name: "SelectedRowsSummary",
                    showInColumn: "SaleAmount",
                    displayFormat: "Sum: {0}",
                    valueFormat: "currency",
                    summaryType: "custom"
                }
            ],
            calculateCustomSummary: function (options) {
                if (options.name === "SelectedRowsSummary") {
                    if (options.summaryProcess === "start") {
                        options.totalValue = 0;
                    }
                    if (options.summaryProcess === "calculate") {
                        if (options.component.isRowSelected(options.value.ID)) {
                            options.totalValue = options.totalValue + options.value.SaleAmount;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

In the section *if (options.summaryProcess === "calculate") {* you can put your custom calc logic, in this case your total count.

Comment: I need total count for pagination that's why I want totalCount.

Comment: Actually I am using CustomStore and fetching just 10 rows of data while totalCount = 120 rows.

Thanks